# remove a child element in a element content with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is a sample html code:

```
<div class="leadContent">
   <span> sentence 1 </span>

   sentence 2

</div>
```

I just want to get sentence 2 (Not span tag and its content)

Is there any way to do this with simple_html_dom?

```
$html->find('div.leadContent', 0)->innertext;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove span tag using outertext:

```
$html->find('div.leadContent span', 0)->outertext = '';
```

then you get the content

```
$html->find('div.leadContent', 0)->innertext;
```

edit:

You can also try this way:

```
$div = $html->find('div.leadContent', 0);
$div->find('span',0)->outertext = '';
```

`$div` will have your content.

Comment: edited my answer adding another option you can try. It's been a while since i used simple_html_dom, but this is the way to remove a undesired element, something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also,

```
echo $html->find('text',2)->plaintext;
```